# DevExpress MetroUI

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Actually I am using DevExpress 12.2.4 Version.
what happened to MetroUI?
Now we cant find

```
using DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.MetroUI;
```

Actually we have designed our application in MetroUI.
Please Help

Comment: have you referenced `DevExpress.XtraBars.vxx.x.dll`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress Breaking Changes List for version v12.2:

**[BC1766](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/WhatsNew/DXperience/files/12.2.2.bc.xml#BC1766)**: The **Metro** term has been replaced with **WindowsUI** in code namespaces and class names.

Because new branding guidelines for Windows 8 have been provided, the use of the name "Metro" is no longer recommended.

This change affected the following classes:

```
MetroUIView
MetroUIViewInfo
MetroUIViewHitInfo
MetroUIViewPainter
MetroUIViewController
MetroUIViewCommand
```

This change affected the following namespaces:

```
DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.MetroUI
DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Dragging.MetroUI
```

---

In other words: The WindowsUI(v12.2) is a next version of MetroUI(v12.1) - you would just replace the `MetroUI` in your code with `WindowsUI`. You can easily perform this operation automatically using the [Project Converter tool](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529), available within the DXperience installation

Answer (score 0):

From what I just saw in their forums they were making MetroUI obsolete in favor of WindowsUI. I have no experience with these, but I can guess 3 possible solutions:

- Keep using the older version
- Update to [`WindowsUI`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsWindowsUI), which might just be renamed `MetroUI`, so you would just need to search/replace `MetroUI` to `WindowsUI` in your code
- If `WindowsUI` is significantly different than `MetroUI` - modify your code to use the new controls.